# Restriction with Upload wizard in Oracle Apex 19.1

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-19.1

In the existing functionality of Apex19.1 I can only upload 45 columns data and remaining number of columns is neither further mapped or added to the table.

Help me with below pointers:

1. Is there a way to increase the number of columns to be mapped with Upload wizard functionality?
2. Only insert statements work in upload wizard although I have put a constraint on ID column but it gives error of Unique Key through Apex Collection. Can you implement update functionality too?

Hope above describes my doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data loading wizard supports MAX 45 columns.

See the `APEX_DATA_PARSER` package which lets you parse CSV files with up to 300 columns. However, you'd still have to code `INSERT` by yourself; Apex can't/won't do it for you.

Another alternative (out of Apex, though) is to use SQL*Loader or its *sub-alternative* - an external table. There's no wizard for any of those options, so yes - you'll have to do some *typing* yourself.